# calling the master class as a type in JsonSubTypes

Tags: java, rest, jackson

Is there any way to call the same class as a type using jackson annotation `@JsonSubTypes`?
Here's the explanation:
I have created this master class that have many sub-types

```
@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type" )
@JsonSubTypes( { @Type( value = FirstClass.class, name = "first" )
                ,@Type( value = SecondClass.class, name = "second" )
                ,@Type( value = ThirdClass.class, name = "third" ) } )
@Data
public abstract class Master {
    public String name;
}
```

for the three classes (FirstClass, SecondClass and ThirdClass) they contain different attributes and in my code I have 4 different conditions

```
if ( inputClass instanceof FirstClass){...}
else if ( inputClass instanceof SecondClass){...}
else if ( inputClass instanceof ThirdClass){...}
else if ( inputClass instanceof Master ){...}
```

My concern is the last condition where the **inputClass has only `name` and `type` attributes and no other field like the rest of the cases** ,so I tried to create a new type by adding this into JsonSubTypes

```
@Type( value = Master.class, name = "fourth" )
```

And I changed the fourth condition into this

```
if ( inputClass instanceof Master ){...}
```

But when I send a rest request using this input

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "type":"fourth"
}
```

I am getting this error:

> JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of com.test.Master,
>   problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types,
>   have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type
>   information; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of com.test.Master

It appears that I will need to create a class without attributes to use it as a type instead of using master and I dont know if there's any better solution

Here's an example for the used classes (first, second and third)

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode( callSuper = true )
@JsonTypeName( "FirstClass" )
public class FirstClass extends Master {

    public FirstClass() { 
    }

    private String attributeA = null;
    //attributeB for SecondClass and attributeC for ThirdClass

}
```

Comment: You should not declare the Master class as abstract then

Comment: @Erwin thanks for your answer, but I just tried that and I got this error Could not resolve type id 'forth' into a subtype of [simple type, class com.test.Master]: known type ids = [Master, first, second, third]

Comment: You put the type id wrong. I have put my answer for the right type id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type" )
@JsonSubTypes( { @Type( value = FirstClass.class, name = "first" )
                ,@Type( value = SecondClass.class, name = "second" )
                ,@Type( value = ThirdClass.class, name = "third" ) } )
public class Master {

    public String name;
}
```

```
if ( master instanceof FirstClass){
...
} else if ( master instanceof SecondClass) {
...
} else if ( master instanceof ThirdClass){
...
} else if ( master instanceof Master ){
...
}
```

and use this request to call the Master condition

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "type":"Master"
}
```

EDIT:
You can use @JsonTypeName for specific name

```
@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type" )
@JsonSubTypes( { @Type( value = FirstClass.class, name = "first" )
                ,@Type( value = SecondClass.class, name = "second" )
                ,@Type( value = ThirdClass.class, name = "third" ) } )
@JsonTypeName("forth")
public class Master {

    public String name;
}
```

request

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "type":"forth"
}
```

Comment: this seems to work but how can we change the type name ex: FourthClass instead of Master

Comment: You can use JsonTypeName, I have added in my answer